# How to shutdown Linux using C++ or Qt without call to "system()"?

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, shutdown

I want to shutdown an Embedded Linux when a close button is pushed on the UI. I know I can do it with a call to `system`:

```
system("shutdown -P now");
```

Ref: [Link](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-shutdown-computer)

But knowing that using `system` is not advised, I'ld like to know if there is another way in C++ to do this (if there is also a specific way to do this using Qt, I'ld also like to know it although a general C++ method is more important).

Comment: Why is `system()` not advised?

Comment: Read about [**DBus**](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html). BTW, there is a `QDBus` api I think.

Comment: @cmannett85 for a very simple reason if the OP is using Qt it means that it would require root privileges within a GUI application, really bad idea. Invoking programs with `system()` almost always represents a security problem.

Comment: @iharob it is an embedded system.

Answer (score 20):

On Linux you can call the [reboot system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html) to poweroff, halt, or reboot.
The following snippet shows how to poweroff a machine, but note that it will of course only work on Linux :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/reboot.h>

int main() {
    reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC1, 
           LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2, 
           LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF, 0);
}
```

Of course, you will need sufficient privileges to use this syscall.

Comment: That's what dbus is for, although since it's an embeded system I don't know if dbus is used, it could be.

Comment: @iharob Indeed, you could also use DBus to talk to ConsoleKit or UPower if they are installed. I wouldn't expect all embedded systems to have them running, though.

Comment: Does this stop running systemd services correctly as `system(reboot)` does ?

Comment: I would recommend calling [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) and probably `usleep`-ing some deciseconds before that `reboot`

Comment: The code in this answer won't work: if you include the correct prototype from `<sys/reboot.h>`, you'll see `int reboot(int __howto)` wrapper instead of the direct system call signature — that's what glibc provides. To really do the call with magic numbers, you have to use `syscall(2)`.

Answer (score 15):

Under glibc you'll need:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/reboot.h>
#include <sys/reboot.h>

int main() {
    sync();
    reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF);
}
```

Again, as always, you'll need to be running with sufficient privileges.

[reboot's man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html)

Answer (score 4):

If your system have *systemd*, then you can use [*logind*](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/) functionality via *D-Bus*. *Qt* solution is the following (just tested):

```
QDBusInterface logind{"org.freedesktop.login1", "/org/freedesktop/login1", "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager", QDBusConnection::systemBus()};
const auto message = logind.callWithArgumentList(QDBus::Block, "CanPowerOff", {});
QDBusPendingReply< QString > canPowerOff = message;
Q_ASSERT(canPowerOff.isFinished());
if (canPowerOff.isError()) {
    const auto error = canPowerOff.error();
    qWarning().noquote()
            << QDBusInterface::tr("Asynchronous call finished with error: %1 (%2)")
               .arg(error.name(), error.message());
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
if (canPowerOff.value() == "yes") {
    QDBusPendingReply<> powerOff = logind.callWithArgumentList(QDBus::Block, "PowerOff", {true, });
    Q_ASSERT(powerOff.isFinished());
    if (powerOff.isError()) {
        const auto error = powerOff.error();
        qWarning().noquote()
                << QDBusInterface::tr("Asynchronous call finished with error: %1 (%2)")
                   .arg(error.name(), error.message());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
} else {
    qCritical().noquote()
            << QCoreApplication::translate("poweroff", "Can't power off: CanPowerOff() result is %1")
               .arg(canPowerOff.value());
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Also possible there is a need to add a file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-enable-shutdown.pkla` to suppress interactive authentication requirement:

```
[Enable shoutdown for users]
Identity=unix-group:users
Action=org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-ignore-inhibit;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: Does anybody really use systemd on an embedded system?  *Shudder.*

Comment: @TobySpeight me. But my embedded system is fat enough to run Ubuntu Server and graphical application with peak RAM=~1.5GB and VRAM=~2GB.

Comment: I guess we have different expectations of what's "embedded", then!

Comment: @TobySpeight sure. For me it is just standalone unmaintained machine. Non-desktop and non-server. Say kiosk.

Comment: @TobySpeight a lot of arm socs are sufficient for running a systemd-based linux, i.e. Yocto Poky distro runs with it by default.

Comment: For anyone else who's not a DBus expert, that wants to enable rebooting as well as powering-off, substitute `CanReboot` for `CanPowerOff` and `Reboot` for `PowerOff`, then you'll need 3 extra rules in the polkit file, substituting `reboot` for `power-off`.

Answer (score 3):

The Qt way is to use `QProcess` to run the shutdown command:

```
QProcess process;
process.startDetached("shutdown -P now");
```

Comment: Thanks! I may end up using this since I can't find which header file includes `reboot` :x (no help page including `man` tells that \o/)

Comment: Er, that's pretty much the same as `system()` - in particular, the command is parsed by a shell.  However, the other `QProcess::startDetached()`, that accepts a `QStringList` of arguments, avoids some of the problems.

Answer (score -3):

If your problem is that you think system() isn't secure, you can use

```
system("/bin/sh shutdown -P now");
```

then you can be sure you're using the right shutdown function.

Comment: As far as I remember on my readings on `system()`, the reasons why it's not recommended go far beyond "using the right shutdown function" :) But thanks!

Comment: This command does not work on my Ubuntu. Says "/bin/sh: 0: Can't open shutdown".

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev because it should be /bin/sh -c <command>